# What is the correct Syntax for MySQL IF statement when comparing variable to nth row from query result?

Tags: mysql

I am writing a Stored Procedure in MySQLWorkbench and want to create an IF statement that sets a variable to true or false.

The condition for this IF statement should compare a previously assigned variable to a nth row from a query result. 
Is there another correct what of doing this?

I have tried to use OFFSET n but this results into a syntax error. Also LIMIT n-1, n doesn't work

```
IF answer_in = (SELECT column FROM table OFFSET n) THEN
   SET x = true;
ELSE
   SET x = false;
END IF;
```

Comment: Maybe... `LIMIT n,1` instead of `OFFSET n` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use `OFFSET`

```
SELECT column FROM table ORDER BY <relevant_col> LIMIT 1 OFFSET n
```

or without offset

```
SELECT column FROM table ORDER BY <relevant_col> LIMIT n,1
```

Comment: Without an `ORDER BY` clause, the sequence of the rows isn't guaranteed. It's very strange to see a `LIMIT` clause in a query without an `ORDER BY`, unless we don't care which row is returned (e.g. checking that there's at least one matching row, with a LIMIT 1 query.)